# SUM of production counts for "overnight work shift" in MS SQL (2019)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sum

I need some help regarding sum of production count for overnight shifts.

The table just contains a timestamp (that is automaticaly generated by SQL server during INSERT), the number of OK produced pieces and the number of NOT OK produced pieces in that given timestamp.

```
CREATE TABLE [machine1](
    [timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [OK] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NOK] [int] NOT NULL
)
ALTER TABLE [machine1] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [timestamp]
```

The table holds values like these (just an example, there are hundreds of lines each day and the time stamps are not fixed like each hour or each 30mins):

| timestamp | OK | NOK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 05:30:00.000 | 15 | 1 |
| 2022-08-01 06:30:00.000 | 18 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-08-01 21:30:00.000 | 10 | 12 |
| 2022-08-01 22:30:00.000 | 0 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-08-01 23:59:00.000 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-08-02 00:01:00.000 | 7 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-08-02 05:30:00.000 | 12 | 4 |
| 2022-08-02 06:30:00.000 | 9 | 3 |

The production works in shifts like so:

1. morning shift: 6:00 -> 14:00
2. afternoon shift: 14:00 -> 22:00
3. night shift: 22:00 -> 6:00 the next day

I have managed to get sums for the morning and afternoon shifts without issues but I can't figure out how to do the sum for the night shift (I have these `SELECT`s for each shift stored as a `VIEW` for easy access).

For the morning shift:

```
SELECT CAST(timestamp AS date) AS Morning,
        SUM(OK) AS SUM_OK,
        SUM(NOK) AS SUM_NOK
FROM [machine1]
WHERE DATEPART(hh,timestamp) >= 6 AND DATEPART(hh,timestamp) < 14
GROUP BY CAST(timestamp AS date)
ORDER BY Morning ASC
```

For the afternoon shift:

```
SELECT CAST(timestamp AS date) AS Afternoon,
        SUM(OK) AS SUM_OK,
        SUM(NOK) AS SUM_NOK
FROM [machine1]
WHERE DATEPART(hh,timestamp) >= 14 AND DATEPART(hh,timestamp) < 22
GROUP BY CAST(timestamp AS date)
ORDER BY Afternoon ASC
```

Since we identify the date of each shift by its start, my idea would be that the result for such SUM of night shift would be

| Night | SUM_OK | SUM_NOK |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | xxx | xxx | for interval **2022-08-01 22:00:00.000 -> 2022-08-02 05:59:59.999** |
| 2022-08-02 | xxx | xxx | for interval **2022-08-02 22:00:00.000 -> 2022-08-03 05:59:59.999** |
| 2022-08-03 | xxx | xxx | for interval **2022-08-03 22:00:00.000 -> 2022-08-04 05:59:59.999** |
| 2022-08-04 | xxx | xxx | for interval **2022-08-04 22:00:00.000 -> 2022-08-05 05:59:59.999** |
| ... | ... | ... |  |

Comment: `(in (22,23) or between (0 and 5))` https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: I can't use this because it sums data from ending night shift and starting night shift of the same day... i already tried this just using different approach: `WHERE DATEPART(hh,timepstamp) >= 22 OR DATEPART(hh,timepstamp) < 6`

Comment: Just use a single query and a conditional case expression to sum values for each desired period.

Comment: `GROUP BY CAST(timestamp AS date)` isn't going to work, as the night shift spans a date. Maybe `GROUP BY CAST(DATEADD(hour, -6, timestamp) AS date)`. You need to decide how you want to group these.

Comment: Convert the time into a relevant shift and then group by that.  How do you want to show the shift that covers 2 dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of trial and error I have probably managed to find the needed solution. Using a subquery I shift all the times in range 00:00:00 -> 05:59:59 to the previous day and then I use that result in same approach as for morning and afternon shift (because now all the production data from night shift are in the same date between 22:00:00 and 23:59:59).

In case anyone needs it in future:

```
SELECT
CAST(nightShift.shiftedTime AS date) AS Night,
SUM(nightShift.OK) AS SUM_OK,
SUM(nightShift.NOK) AS SUM_NOK
FROM
(SELECT
  CASE  WHEN (DATEPART(hh, timestamp) < 6 AND DATEPART(hh, timestamp) >= 4) THEN DATEADD(HOUR, -6, timestamp)
        WHEN (DATEPART(hh, timestamp) < 4 AND DATEPART(hh, timestamp) >= 2) THEN DATEADD(HOUR, -4, timestamp)
        WHEN (DATEPART(hh, timestamp) < 2 AND DATEPART(hh, timestamp) >= 0) THEN DATEADD(HOUR, -2, timestamp)
        END AS shiftedTime,     
  [OK],
  [NOK]
  FROM [machine1]
  WHERE (DATEPART(hh, cas) >= 0 AND DATEPART(hh, cas) < 6)) nightShift

WHERE DATEPART(hh,nightShift.shiftedTime) >= 22
GROUP BY CAST(nightShift.shiftedTime AS date)
ORDER BY Night ASC
```

PS: If there is anything wrong with this approach, please feel free to correct me as I'm just newbie in SQL. So far this seems to do exactly what I needed.